# Paypal Rest-API Account

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have some troubles using the paypal rest-api with java.

What i have done so far.

1. Creating Account on paypal developer site.
2. Creating Sandbox Account with type Business(pro)
3. Creating Rest-App and selected my created sandbox account

I used some example code from the github examples and my operations are working so far I can see.

The Problem is when I create a creditcard with the following code:

```
        CreditCard creditCard = new CreditCard();
        creditCard.setExpireMonth(11);
        creditCard.setExpireYear(2018);
        creditCard.setNumber("4417119669820331");
        creditCard.setType("visa");
        APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
        CreditCard created = creditCard.create(apiContext);
        System.out.println(created.getId());
```

The print in the console is like "CARD-01E4XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXBWHI"

When i use the get Method i recieve a json with alle the creditcard information

```
        CreditCard c = CreditCard.get(accessToken, "CARD-01E4XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXBWHI");
        System.out.println(c);
```

So I think there is no problem with my code and the calls I make. But When I watch the profile of my sandbox account via paypal developer site there is no creditcard. Even when I log in via sandbox.paypal into my sandbox account there are no informations about creditcards. I used the credentials of my Rest-App (same as my sandbox account credentials).

My Question: On which Account I added the Creditcard? How can I find out on which Account I'm currently working via Rest-Api. Can i specify on which account I want to work? (I think it's specified by credentials?)

I hope someone can help me, because I tried a lot but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The call you're making is a [Vault](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-vault-overview/) call. Vault is a means of storing card data with PayPal, but it *does not* assign that card to a given PayPal account.